# Como criar um arquivo de configuração no Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel

Gostaria de saber como criar, importar e utilizar novos arquivos de configuração em um projeto Laravel 4.

Com isso, quero dizer, arquivos do projeto e configurações próprias. Por exemplo: Gostaria de criar um arquivo que tivesse algumas informações estáticas do projeto, sem a necessidade de persisti-las no banco de dados.

**Exemplo:**

```php
<?php 
  $config = array(
    'titulo_padrao' => 'Site do João',
    'meta_keywords' => 'palavra1, palavra2, palavra3',
    'meta_description' => 'Dramatically repurpose covalent niches vis-a-vis resource sucking benefits. Authoritatively productize.',
    'script_ga' => 'script_aqui',
    'grupo_administradores' => array(1,2,3),
    'grupo_usuarios' => array(4,5),
    'etc' => '...'
  );
?>
```

Comment: O link do Brayan, tem todos as funcionalidades!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Você pode criar arquivos na pasta de configurações, `nome_do_seu_arquivo.php`, e acessar as propriedades via:

```php
Config::get('nome_do_seu_arquivo.nome_da_propriedade');
```

Ou:

```php
Config::get('nome_do_seu_arquivo.nome_do_array_da_propriedade.nome_da_propriedade');
```

Answer (score 7):

Crie um arquivo php dentro da pasta `app/config/myconfig.php` (pode ser qualquer nome):

```php
<?php 
  return  array(
    'titulo_padrao' => 'Site do João',
    'meta_keywords' => 'palavra1, palavra2, palavra3',
    'meta_description' => 'Dramatically repurpose covalent niches vis-a-vis resource sucking benefits. Authoritatively productize.',
    'script_ga' => 'script_aqui',
    'grupo_administradores' => array(1,2,3),
    'grupo_usuarios' => array(4,5),
    'etc' => '...'
  );
```

Para acessar uma informação, utilize:

```
Config::get('myconfig.titulo_padrao');
```

Para maiores informações http://laravel.com/docs/configuration

Comment: Vale notar que o Laravel utiliza o recurso:  
    $cfg = include("app/config/myconfig.php");  
A variável $cfg recebe o *return* que há no arquivo incluído.

Answer (score 2):

Eu fiz assim quando precisei:

```php
<?php
/*
|---------------------------------------------------
| File: application/config/_sysvars.php
|---------------------------------------------------
|
| Configurações estáticas para uso no site
*/

return array(
    //=========== Configurações principais===========//
    //Email cadastrado no PagSeguro e outros sistemas de recebimento.
    'email_pagseguro' => "xxxxxx@uol.com.br",
    //Identificador Paypal
    'email_paypal' => "xxxxx@gmail.com",
    //Identificador Moip
    'email_moip' => "xxxx@gmail.com",
    //Site Title:
    'title' => 'Dummy Hans - LARAVEL',
);
?>
```

**No controller:**

```php
<?php
/*
|---------------------------------------------------
| File: application/controller/HomeController.php
|---------------------------------------------------
|
| Controler para a Home.
*/
class HomeController extends BaseController {

    /* The layout that should be used for responses.
     */
    protected $layout = 'layouts.master';

    public function showHome() {

        $sysvars = Config::get('_sysvars'); //esta na pasta app/config/_sysvars.php

        foreach ($sysvars as $key => $value ) {
            $data["$key"]=$value;
        }
        //dd($data);

        //Renderiza a view v_home
        $this->layout->content = View::make('v_home',$data);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: pode mostrar como fez para implementar o Pagseguro no Laravel? até hoje não consegui, desde já agradeço.

Comment: mandou bem, isso é mais fácil, mais vc acha melhor colocar na App do que seguir o padrão e colocar na config?

Comment: Hoje eu colocaria na config. Na época me parecia menos confuso e seguro colocar na App

Answer (score 0):

Complementando as respostas, para quem não segue fielmente a estrutura padrão do Framework. Pois bem, eu tenho uma pasta "domínio" da aplicação, que herda o nome dela, por exemplo:

```
- app
    - Acme
        - Config
        - Models
        - Repositories
        - Services
        - Queues
        - ...
    - storages
    - tests
    - config        
    - ...
```

Observe que dentro de `Acme` eu tenho uma pasta `Config`. Desta forma, eu consigo separar as configurações dos componentes do Framework com às da lógica da minha aplicação. A `app/config` é mantida, com todas as configurações padrões.

Para fazer o Framework entender que `Acme/Config` é um namespace de "arquivos de configuração", você pode adicionar a seguinte linha no final do arquivo `app/start/global.php`:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Acme Config Namespace
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

Config::addNamespace('Acme', app_path('Acme/Config'));
```

Feito assim, vamos supor que você tenha este arquivo de configuração:

```
- app
    - Acme
        - Config
            - social.php
```

Você poderá acessá-lo, por exemplo, da seguinte maneira:

```php
\Config::get('Acme::social.facebook');
```

`Acme::` é para indicar o namespace em que o Framework precisa procurar o arquivo de configuração. `social` é o nome do arquivo e `facebook` uma chave do array.

Answer (score 0):

Note que, para alterar essas configurações, o `Config::set()` não irá salvar o arquivo como poderia se esperar.

Tu terá que implementar isso por conta, e em se tratando de arquivos de configuração em PHP onde normalmente se deseja preservar possíveis comentários, isso pode se tornar complicado. No caso de não haver comentários, [`var_export()`](http://www.php.net/var_export) será o suficiente.

Caso se deseje preservar os comentários (algo desejável ao alterar os arquivos de configuração do Laravel, por exemplo), recomenda-se usar o pacote [*Laravel Setting*](https://github.com/Phil-F/Setting), instalável pelo próprio Composer. Ele permite criar, ler, alterar e apagar diretivas de configurações próprias por meio de arquivos JSON, possuindo ainda *fallback* para as diretivas de configurações padrões (arquivos PHP).